# Post from form not working

Tags: php, mysql

When I click the submit button , the imputed data should go into the query bellow , However it doesn't.

It seems that the value of the button is being used instead.

Can someone figure out why it doesn't work. Its the same code being used for my login page and that works.

It goes to the else part of the if statement

Error :

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM test_set WHERE Room_Code='room'' at line 1
```

Query :

```
if (isset($_POST['room']))
    {
    require "connect.php";

    if (count($_POST) > 0)
        {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, FROM test_set WHERE Room_Code='" . $_POST["room"] . "'");
        if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
}
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if (is_array($row))
            {
            $_SESSION["Room_ID"] = $row['id'];
            header("Location: ../views/student/question.php?id='" . $_SESSION["Room_ID"] . "'");
            }
          else
            {
            echo "No";
            }
        }
    }
```

Form :

```
 <form method="POST" name="room" action="../../config/functions.php">
            <label for="room" class="sr-only">Room Code</label>
            <input type="text" id="room" name="room" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter Room Code">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-3" name="room" value="room">
        </form>
```

**Edit:**

Still not working also changing in this way:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM test_set WHERE Room_Code='" . $_POST["room"] . "'");
```

Comment: I have re-edited your post. Please don't change your original code, otherwise answers have not sense. Added un-destructive edit instead

Comment: Can you post the new error message after the changes you've applied?

Comment: @drakyoko see edit 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `,` from your query:

SELECT id`,`

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM test_set 
WHERE Room_Code='" . $_POST["room"] . "'");
```

Comment: Iv just noticed this , test and its not working . It kppes going to the else part of the iff statement

Comment: if you validate the query this will occur in one case, when your table doesn't contain data or your query doesn't return data

Comment: @JohnyChew you can echo your query: echo "SELECT id FROM test_set 
WHERE Room_Code='" . $_POST["room"] . "'" - and run it in mysql, if it doesn't return data, **No** will be output

Comment: It started working kind of (cleared my cache) see edit 2

Comment: @JohnyChew remove single quota to be: header("Location: ../views/student/question.php?id=" . $_SESSION["Room_ID"] );

Answer (score 1):

The value of the button is used because the name you assigned to the submit button is 'room': the same name you're using for the input text. Remove the name attribute from the submit button and it should work.

**after edit2**

change

```
header("Location: ../views/student/question.php?id='" . $_SESSION["Room_ID"] . "'");
```

to

```
header("Location: ../views/student/question.php?id=" . $_SESSION["Room_ID"]);
```

you don't have to quote variables in the query string

Comment: And the form name is "room" too. Might cause a problem.